# Compactness of $C(X,X)$

Tags: gn.general-topology

I am not an expert of this area but I need help to answer this question: For a compact metric space $X$, let $C(X,X)$ be the space of all continuous functions $X\to X$, equipped with the uniform metric 
$$d(f,g)=\sup_x d(f(x),g(x)).$$
Can we say the space $C(X,X)$ is compact?

Comment: For $X=[0,1]$ it will be non-compact.

Comment: @erz Thank you so much.

Comment: See the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzelà–Ascoli_theorem).

Comment: Note that a compact metric space is always complete and separable.

Comment: 2YCor yes thank you.

Comment: @M.Shahryari it's quite trivial to find $X$ with $C(X,X)$ not compact, so maybe you should reformulate the question taking this into account (e.g., asking about a characterization of $X$ such that $C(X,X)$ is compact). Note that (for $X$ compact) this is equivalent to asking when $C(X,X)$ is closed in $X^X$, and hence a related question is [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286803/).

Comment: @YCor, Indeed I only need the case when $X=A^G$ the shift space over finite alphabet $A$ and a f.g group $G$. The set of all cellular automata is a closed subset in this case but I want to see if it is compact or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this space is (almost, see the comment by YCor) never compact except for trivial cases (i.e. the compact set $X$ having only finitely many points).
For more information on the topology (which is colloquially known as the compact-open topology) of the space you are asking about, see e.g. the book Engelking: General topology. (Chapters 2.6 and 3.4 will have most of the information you could possibly need).

Thanks for the clarification by @YCor, the never compact of the original answer was a bit hasty and comes from my use of these spaces where $X$ is always locally euclidean (i.e. the $X$ should be a manifold). Which is of course not necessary.

Comment: This seems to be in contradiction with [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/188735/14094), which says that there exists an infinite connected compact metrizable space, in which every continuous self-map is identity or constant.

Comment: Still for $X$ compact metrizable $C(X,X)$ is non-compact in many cases, notably (a) when $X$ has infinitely many connected components (b) when $X$ contains a non-trivial arc. Also, for $X$ compact metrizable $C(X,[0,1])$ is compact iff $X$ is finite.

Comment: @YCor so $C(A^G, A^G)$ is not compact, because $A^G$ is totally disconnected ($G$ is f.g).

Comment: @YCor: Thanks for the correction, I am always thinking nice metrisable spaces, i.e. manifolds...